# Spring AOP - method aspect is not invoked

Tags: spring, aop

Sorry: Google Traductor (english basic)

Interface implemented by aspect:

```
public interface MinReader {

    void interceptThoughts();
}
```

MinReader class that implements the interface, which contains the "Aspect"

```
@Aspect
public class Magician implements MinReader {

    @Pointcut("within(paquetea.paqueteb.*)")
    public void thinking() {

    }

    @Override
    @Before("thinking()")
    public void interceptThoughts() {
        // Codigo
    }
}
```

This is a part of my JavaConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class SpringIdolConfig {

    @Bean
    public MinReader magician() {
        return new Magician();
    }

     // Otros bean
}
```

the problem is that the "interceptThoughts" method is never invoked.

My "solution" is to change the return type of method "magician" in my JavaConfig:
"MinReader" -> "Magician"

```
@Bean
public Magician magician() {
    return new Magician();
}
```

- Why is that?
- Is there any way to use "MinReader" instead of "Magician"?

UPDATE: these are the other beans:

```
package paquetea.paqueteb;

public interface Thinker {  
    void thinkOfSomething(String thoughts);
}

package paquetea.paqueteb;

public class Volunteer implements Thinker {
    @Override
    public void thinkOfSomething(String thoughts) {
        //code
    }
}
```

This is my full javaconfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class SpringIdolConfig {

    @Bean
    public MinReader magician() {
        return new Magician();
    }

    @Bean
    public Thinker volunteer() {
        return new Volunteer();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your spring XML look like? Or, what about your in-code configuration of beans and aspects?

Comment: Can you show us your bean configuration?

Comment: post update: add beans y javaconfig full

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a bit, but I think one of your problems is that you've got the pointcut expression wrong. If I've read [the examples in here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html) right, you should use:

```
@Pointcut("within(paquetea.paqueteb..*)")
```

Note the `..*`, and not the `.*` that you had. I find that when I get pointcuts wrong, they can be very difficult to debug, as their normal way of failing is to just silently not attach to anything. (My preferred technique is to attach to methods annotated with a custom annotation; that makes it easy to control what's happening and easy to debug.)